# Rebuild Database ViewVC

Tags: python, database, centos7

I wanna rebuild the ViewVC database and I got the following error:

[root@localhost bin]# /usr/local/viewvc-1.1.26/bin/cvsdbadmin rebuild /usr/local/rancid/tar/CVSROOT/

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/viewvc-1.1.26/bin/cvsdbadmin", line 44, in

```
import cvsdb
```

File "/usr/local/viewvc-1.1.26/lib/cvsdb.py", line 21, in

```
import dbi
```

File "/usr/local/viewvc-1.1.26/lib/dbi.py", line 18, in

```
import MySQLdb
```

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Please can you help me with this???

Thanks.